# php.ini disable get_magic_quotes_gpc

Tags: php, ini

I've been told by my hosting company that putting a `php.ini` file in the folder that my domain is mapped to will disable `magic_quotes_gpc`. I created a text file and saved it as `php.ini` and uploaded it via FTP to the mapped folder. It did not fix my issue though. Here is what my `.ini` file looks like

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
```

I also tried

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
```

That did not work either.

when testing a `\` is still appearing in the text. My experience with `.ini` files is zero and my hosting company offer very little support. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `phpinfo()` will you the current in-effect settings, and where the various overrides are coming from), e.g. which ini files were used. Your host may have disabled per-directory .ini files, in which case you might have to use a .htaccess `php_value magic_quotes_gpc 0` type override.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks a lot for the `phpinfo()` tip. This was a huge help in finding the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the full location of the folder you are putting that `php.ini` in?

You need to make sure that its in your home directory not in your public folder.

You can also add `php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off` to your `.htaccess` file if you have one, and it should do the same thing.

Comment: It is in the home directory, the same folder in which the `index.php` resides. I tried adding that to the `.htaccess` but it produced an error.

Comment: Is the file you trying to run in a sub-folder or the same folder as the php.ini file?

Comment: the `.htaccess` is in the same folder as the `php.ini` file

Comment: I mean is the php.ini in the same directory as the file thats having the slashes issue, some hosting providers require the php.ini to be in your home directory, others require it to be in every folder and subfolder that you have code in. Try putting the php.ini file in the same folder as the file thats causing the slashes issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It needed to be in the home folder and the folder which had the issue. I thought the rule would cascade down but as you point out this is not always the case. I tested it by creating a file with `phpinfo()` in it and kept checking when the rule was being applied.